# "causative of negative" vs "negative of causative"?

Tags: grammar, usage, nuances

[Wikipedia (Japanese Verb Conjugation)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_verb_conjugation):

> Negatives [verb negative-conjugations] are not normally made into causatives. Instead, a negative ending is added to the causative of the verb. Thus, for example, Tabesasenai: "Do not let eat".

From the quote above, we can see that although negatives are not normally made into causatives, they *can* be made into causatives.

What is the difference between a causative-of-negative and a negative-of-causative? How do we decide when to use which?

For example, what is the difference in nuance between「これを[食べさせない](https://www.google.com.sg/search?sugexp=chrome,mod=4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=%22%E9%A3%9F%E3%81%B9%E3%81%95%E3%81%9B%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%22)」and「これを[食べなくさせる](https://www.google.com.sg/search?sugexp=chrome,mod=4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=%22%E9%A3%9F%E3%81%B9%E3%81%AA%E3%81%8F%E3%81%95%E3%81%9B%E3%82%8B%22)」?

Comment: I won't let you eat VS I will let you not to eat ?

Comment: 食べなくさせる has a nuance "to make someone quit/stop eating".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Causative has two meanings: **forcing** and **allowing**. Let me first illustrate the semantic distinction considering only "forcing":

- Negation of causative of P = "not force doing P"
- Causative of negation of P = "force to not do P"

In general, there is a mismatch between the hierarchy in the syntactic structure (at the surface) and the hierarchy in the logical structure. For example, the English expression `I cannot do P` does not mean "It is possible ('can') for me to not do P" (potential of negation of P) but means "It is not the case that I can do P" (negation of potential of P). What the article is probably saying is that `tabe-sase-nai` syntactically looks like the hierarchy is "negation of causative of eat", but its meaning is "causative of negation of eat", or "forcing not to eat".

Now, there is the same semantic distinction for "allowing":

- Negation of causative of P = "not (particularly) allow doing P"
- Causative of negation of P = "allow not doing P"

Note that "forcing" and "allowing" are logically connected under the following 
formulae from modal logic (~ = negation, ◇ = possibility operator (i.e., "allowing" in this case), □ = necessity operator (i.e., "forcing" in this case)):

> ~◇P = □~P
>   ~□P = ◇~P

From this, the expression `tabe-sase-nai` which means "forcing not to eat" can also be paraphrased as "not allowing to eat".

Comment: Can you clarify the itemized list at the beginning?  To me, “not allow doing P” exactly means “force not to do P,” and “not force doing P” exactly means “allow not doing P,” so the correspondence among the four in the list is not what I expect.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto Thanks for pointing that out. I somehow had it the other way around. I hope it makes sense now.

Comment: Thanks.  Actually my confusion had another layer, but now I think I understand the correspondence.  You are referring to two meanings of causative (“allow” and “force”), and you construct negation of causative and causative of negation in both meanings.  The difficult point for me was that “not force doing P” exactly looks like the same thing as “allow not doing P.”  (If you do not force me to swim, I am allowed not to swim.)  It might become easier to understand if you focus on one of the two meanings of causative first, and then add an explanation that causative can sometimes mean the other.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto You are right. I packed two meanings into one paradigm. "Force" is related to the necessity operator □, and "allow" is related to the possibility operator ◇. I actually had a bit of concern that it might be misleading. And that let me end up writing the formulae from modal logic. Let me try to edit again.

Comment: @sawa Your last paragraph states that the expression "tabe-sase-nai" means "forcing you not to eat". But doesn't "tabe-sase-nai" mean "not forcing you to eat" ?

Comment: @Pacerier No. That is the point.

Comment: @sawa Hmm, with that we have "tabe-sase-nai" meaning "forcing you not to eat", and "tabe-naku-saseru" meaning "forcing you to not eat". But since "forcing you not to eat" and "forcing you to not eat" is the same thing, what is the difference between "tabe-sase-nai" and "tabe-naku-saseru" ?

Comment: @Pacerier `tabe-naku saseru` is a totally different expression. It means "forcing to stop eating".